# Read another Chrome Extension's manifest.json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a modular extension that can be extended by other extensions. I'm looking for a way to read the extension's manifest.json or perhaps a custom file, like widgets.json.

I tried [this](http://www.martinsikora.com/accessing-manifest-json-in-a-google-chrome-extension), even with the permission `<all_urls>`, but unfortunately was faced with this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load chrome-extension://aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj/manifest.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

Is there any other way that I could exchange small, simple bits of data between the extensions? I'm currently using `chrome.extension.sendRequest`, but this is proving to be a tax on memory in the background.html. In addition, it also makes it where Hosted Apps cannot embed widgets within their app.

I'd very much appreciate any assistance.

Note: I also realize jsonp is an option, but one I'd rather not take. Malicious extensions could easily result in a vulnerability.

Comment: Which field do you want to read from manifest?

Comment: A custom field, "widgets". The extension I'm working on has widgets that can be created by anyone. Sadly, my current method doesn't work for Hosted Apps (chrome.extension.sendRequest).

Comment: If you want to let other extensions and apps talk to yours, you can make your extension have an html page that's listed under "web_accessible_resources", accepts messages, and writes to localStorage. Other extensions will create an iframe embedding that page into their background page, they can use postMessage to send messages to it, and the page will write the messages localStorage. Your extension background page can then read the messages out of localStorage.

Answer (score 3):

> Malicious extensions could easily result in a vulnerability.

Which is exactly why Chrome doesn't allow one extension to look into another's garden.

So no, Chromium doesn't support this. You have several options:

1. File an enhancement request that implements "extension points" which allow different extensions to talk to each other without an additional, external server.
2. Share the data at build time: Create a skeleton extension which contains the shared data and build all "child" extensions using the same skeleton. This means that you'll have to deploy all extensions at the same time and it won't allow your extensions to exchange runtime data but it might help.
3. Create an external server which allows all your extensions to talk to each other. Probably not realistic, just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I don't really see the harm in being able to read another extension's manifest.json. Moreover, extensions themselves can cause far more harm to websites users visit than to other extensions, and this is already possible. I don't really like any of those options `:[` I'll keep trying things; there has to be a way.